# Magento 2 : How to Get Product SKU Quantity Displayed on Details Page

Tags: magento2, product, qty

Magento 2, How to get the product SKU quantity displayed on product details page。

[image]

Comment: You are searching for simple product of configurable product, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy getQty() method on product object.

So you can use two ways.

The unsuggested one which uses object manager:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
echo $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
```

**The suggested way**:

```
$product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
```

Keep in mind that you'll load all the stock object which has also min_qty,max_qty, etc properties.

Comment: I would not suggest to you object Manager from now @Davide

Comment: @BhupendraJadeja Edited my answer.